# How can I filter in SetSearchFilter only objects that contain specific component/s?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the CustomEditor script I color in yellow objects that have attached a specific component in this case Mesh Renderer.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
//Adapted from Unity3DCollege YouTube Video Tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pdDrY8Mc2lU
[InitializeOnLoad]
public class CustomHierarchy : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static Vector2 offset = new Vector2(0, 2);
    public static Color gameObjectFontColor = Color.black;
    public static Color prefabOrgFontColor = Color.black;
    public static Color prefabModFontColor = Color.white;
    public static Color inActiveColor = new Color(0.01f, 0.4f, 0.25f);
    public static Color meshRendererColor = Color.yellow;
    public static List<string> componentsList = new List<string>();

    static CustomHierarchy()
    {
        EditorApplication.hierarchyWindowItemOnGUI += HandleHierarchyWindowItemOnGUI;
    }
    private static void HandleHierarchyWindowItemOnGUI(int instanceID, Rect selectionRect)
    {
        Color fontColor = gameObjectFontColor;
        Color backgroundColor = new Color(.76f, .76f, .76f);
        FontStyle styleFont = FontStyle.Normal;
        var obj = EditorUtility.InstanceIDToObject(instanceID);
        GameObject gameObj = EditorUtility.InstanceIDToObject(instanceID) as GameObject;

        if (Selection.instanceIDs.Contains(instanceID))
        {
            backgroundColor = new Color(0.24f, 0.48f, 0.90f);
        }
        if (obj != null)
        {
            var prefabType = PrefabUtility.GetPrefabType(obj);
            if (gameObj.activeInHierarchy == false)
            {
                backgroundColor = inActiveColor;
            }

            if (prefabType == PrefabType.PrefabInstance)
            {
                styleFont = FontStyle.Bold;
                PropertyModification[] prefabMods = PrefabUtility.GetPropertyModifications(obj);
                foreach (PropertyModification prefabMod in prefabMods)
                {
                    if (prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_Name" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalPosition.x" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalPosition.y" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalPosition.z" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalRotation.x" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalRotation.y" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalRotation.z" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalRotation.w" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_RootOrder" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_IsActive")
                    {
                        if (gameObj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>() == true)
                            fontColor = meshRendererColor;
                        else
                            fontColor = prefabModFontColor;

                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (fontColor != prefabModFontColor)
                {
                    if (gameObj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>() == true)
                        fontColor = meshRendererColor;
                    else
                        fontColor = prefabOrgFontColor;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (gameObj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>() == true)
                    fontColor = meshRendererColor;
            }
            Rect offsetRect = new Rect(selectionRect.position + offset, selectionRect.size);
            EditorGUI.DrawRect(selectionRect, backgroundColor);
            EditorGUI.LabelField(offsetRect, obj.name, new GUIStyle()
            {
                normal = new GUIStyleState() { textColor = fontColor },
                fontStyle = styleFont
            }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

In the EditorWindow script I'm using the SetSearchFilter:

```
using System;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Reflection;

public class HierarchyEditor : EditorWindow
{
    private static SearchableEditorWindow hierarchy { get; set; }
    private string filterText = "";

    [MenuItem("Tools/Hierarchy Editor")]
    public static void ShowWindow()
    {
        GetWindow<HierarchyEditor>("HierarchyEditor");
    }
    private void OnGUI()
    {
        CustomHierarchy.gameObjectFontColor = EditorGUILayout.ColorField("Original Font Color", CustomHierarchy.gameObjectFontColor);
        CustomHierarchy.prefabOrgFontColor = EditorGUILayout.ColorField("Prefab Original Font Color", CustomHierarchy.prefabOrgFontColor);
        CustomHierarchy.prefabModFontColor = EditorGUILayout.ColorField("Prefab Modified Font Color", CustomHierarchy.prefabModFontColor);
        CustomHierarchy.inActiveColor = EditorGUILayout.ColorField("Inactive Color", CustomHierarchy.inActiveColor);
        CustomHierarchy.meshRendererColor = EditorGUILayout.ColorField("Mesh Renderer Color", CustomHierarchy.meshRendererColor);

        filterText = GUI.TextField(new Rect(30,190,120,30),filterText, 25);

        SetSearchFilter(filterText, 1);
    }

    public const int FILTERMODE_ALL = 0;
    public const int FILTERMODE_NAME = 1;
    public const int FILTERMODE_TYPE = 2;

    public static void SetSearchFilter(string filter, int filterMode)
    {
        SearchableEditorWindow[] windows = (SearchableEditorWindow[])Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(SearchableEditorWindow));

        foreach (SearchableEditorWindow window in windows)
        {
            if (window.GetType().ToString() == "UnityEditor.SceneHierarchyWindow")
            {
                hierarchy = window;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (hierarchy == null)
            return;

        MethodInfo setSearchType = typeof(SearchableEditorWindow).GetMethod("SetSearchFilter", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        object[] parameters = new object[] { filter, filterMode, false };

        setSearchType.Invoke(hierarchy, parameters); 
    }
}
```

Here I'm typing in the filterText TextField and it's filtering by name in this case.

But I want to filter by name but also to filter only objects that attached to them a Mesh Renderer component. Not the FILTERMODE_TYPE but objects that have attached with Mesh Renderer component. So the filter mode should be Name(1) but also to filter at the same time objects with mesh renderer.

I tried to add to the OnGUI two lines:
The two lines are:

```
System.Type type = SceneModeUtility.SearchBar(typeof(BoxCollider), typeof(MeshRenderer));
SceneModeUtility.SearchForType(type);
```

But then in the EditorWindow I see 3 icons All BoxCollider MeshRenderer.
If I click on BoxCollider it's filtering all objects with boxcollider but then when I'm typing a name in the hierarchy search bar it will filter all objects with the name and box collider but then when I click on the editorwindow again it's changing it to the All icon. Same for the meshrenderer.

And I can't select both boxcollider and meshrenderer I can select only one of them.

Screenshot of the EditorWindow:

[image: EditorWindow]

```
private void OnGUI()
    {
        CustomHierarchy.gameObjectFontColor = EditorGUILayout.ColorField("Original Font Color", CustomHierarchy.gameObjectFontColor);
        CustomHierarchy.prefabOrgFontColor = EditorGUILayout.ColorField("Prefab Original Font Color", CustomHierarchy.prefabOrgFontColor);
        CustomHierarchy.prefabModFontColor = EditorGUILayout.ColorField("Prefab Modified Font Color", CustomHierarchy.prefabModFontColor);
        CustomHierarchy.inActiveColor = EditorGUILayout.ColorField("Inactive Color", CustomHierarchy.inActiveColor);
        CustomHierarchy.meshRendererColor = EditorGUILayout.ColorField("Mesh Renderer Color", CustomHierarchy.meshRendererColor);

        multipleComponents = GUI.Toggle(new Rect(30, 160, 120, 30), multipleComponents, "Multiple components");
        if(multipleComponents == true)
        {
            GUI.enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            GUI.enabled = false;
        }
        multipleComponentsString = GUI.TextField(new Rect(30, 180, 120, 30), multipleComponentsString, 25);

        GUI.enabled = true;
        filterText = GUI.TextField(new Rect(30, 230, 120, 30), filterText, 25);

        System.Type type = SceneModeUtility.SearchBar(typeof(BoxCollider), typeof(MeshRenderer));
        SceneModeUtility.SearchForType(type);
    }
```

Comment: It probably works the same way the project's search window and Hierarchy filter does.  Use _"t:"_ with the component name, a space, then the name filter string.  So _"t:MeshCollider Ham"_ will match any object with `MeshCollider` components that has "Ham" somewhere in the name.

Comment: @Foggzie Great thanks. So I was working for nothing but at least I learned something.

Comment: @Foggzie What the searcher can't find for example is objects with mesh renderer and also box collider. for example I have 40 objects with mesh renderer some have box collider. Is there a way to filter only the objects with the mesh renderer and also with box collider ? (Multiple components filtering)

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do multiple but you can use base classes so instead of `MeshCollider` and `BoxCollider` you can just do `Collider`.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you're using reflection to do this. You don't have to. There is an undocumented API called `SceneModeUtility` that can be used to search Objects in the Editor. See the non-official API for this [here](http://anchan828.hatenablog.jp/entry/2013/04/29/230652). It can be easily translated into English with a Chrome browser.

If you just want to search and filter an Object with a component (`MeshRenderer`) in the SearchField in the Editor:

```
SceneModeUtility.SearchForType(typeof(MeshRenderer));
```

To filter the search with multiple components on a GameObject and return the result:

```
System.Type type = SceneModeUtility.SearchBar(typeof(MeshRenderer), typeof(Rigidbody));
```

You can pass as many components as you wish to the `SearchBar` function.

Comment: I tried to add this to lines inside the OnGUI: System.Type type = SceneModeUtility.SearchBar(typeof(BoxCollider), typeof(MeshRenderer));
  SceneModeUtility.SearchForType(type); But then in the editorwindow I have 3 icons All BoxCollider MeshRenderer if I click on box collider it will filter all objects with box collider and same for mesh renderer but then when I type name in the searhc bar in the hierarchy it's changing it to all. And I can select or box collider or mesh renderer but not both types.

Comment: I updated my question edited with what I tried and a screenshot.