# How can I filter and hide objects that are not containing multiple components?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
//Adapted from Unity3DCollege YouTube Video Tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pdDrY8Mc2lU
[InitializeOnLoad]
public class CustomHierarchy : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static Vector2 offset = new Vector2(0, 2);
    public static Color gameObjectFontColor = Color.black;
    public static Color prefabOrgFontColor = Color.black;
    public static Color prefabModFontColor = Color.white;
    public static Color inActiveColor = new Color(0.01f, 0.4f, 0.25f);
    public static Color meshRendererColor = Color.yellow;
    public static List<string> componentsList = new List<string>();

    static CustomHierarchy()
    {
        EditorApplication.hierarchyWindowItemOnGUI += HandleHierarchyWindowItemOnGUI;
    }
    private static void HandleHierarchyWindowItemOnGUI(int instanceID, Rect selectionRect)
    {
        Color fontColor = gameObjectFontColor;
        Color backgroundColor = new Color(.76f, .76f, .76f);
        FontStyle styleFont = FontStyle.Normal;
        var obj = EditorUtility.InstanceIDToObject(instanceID);
        GameObject gameObj = EditorUtility.InstanceIDToObject(instanceID) as GameObject;

        if (Selection.instanceIDs.Contains(instanceID))
        {
            backgroundColor = new Color(0.24f, 0.48f, 0.90f);
        }
        if (obj != null)
        {
            var prefabType = PrefabUtility.GetPrefabType(obj);
            if (gameObj.activeInHierarchy == false)
            {
                backgroundColor = inActiveColor;
            }

            if (prefabType == PrefabType.PrefabInstance)
            {
                styleFont = FontStyle.Bold;
                PropertyModification[] prefabMods = PrefabUtility.GetPropertyModifications(obj);
                foreach (PropertyModification prefabMod in prefabMods)
                {
                    if (prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_Name" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalPosition.x" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalPosition.y" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalPosition.z" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalRotation.x" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalRotation.y" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalRotation.z" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalRotation.w" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_RootOrder" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_IsActive")
                    {
                        if (HasAllComponents(gameObj, typeof(MeshRenderer), typeof(BoxCollider)))
                        {
                            fontColor = meshRendererColor;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            gameObj.hideFlags = gameObj.hideFlags | HideFlags.HideInHierarchy;
                            fontColor = prefabModFontColor;
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (fontColor != prefabModFontColor)
                {
                    if (HasAllComponents(gameObj, typeof(MeshRenderer), typeof(BoxCollider)))
                    {
                        fontColor = meshRendererColor;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        gameObj.hideFlags = gameObj.hideFlags | HideFlags.HideInHierarchy;
                        fontColor = prefabOrgFontColor;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(HasAllComponents(gameObj, typeof(MeshRenderer), typeof(BoxCollider)))
                    fontColor = meshRendererColor;
            }
            Rect offsetRect = new Rect(selectionRect.position + offset, selectionRect.size);
            EditorGUI.DrawRect(selectionRect, backgroundColor);
            EditorGUI.LabelField(offsetRect, obj.name, new GUIStyle()
            {
                normal = new GUIStyleState() { textColor = fontColor },
                fontStyle = styleFont
            }
            );
        }
    }

    public static bool HasAllComponents(GameObject gameObject, params System.Type[] types)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < types.Length; i++)
        {
            if (gameObject.GetComponent(types[i]) == null)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

With the method HasAllComponents I'm checking if objects have multiple components attached and color this objects in yellow.

Now I want to hide from the Hierarchy the rest of objects those that don't have multiple components.

I tried to add in the else:

```
gameObj.hideFlags = gameObj.hideFlags | HideFlags.HideInHierarchy;
```

But that's hiding all the objects from the hierarchy.
I want to make some kind of filter and display in the Hierarchy only objects with multiple components.

Comment: Make sure that your `HasAllComponents` function is working properly. Put `Debug.Log(gameObj.name)` in the `else` statement when calling this function. It should print objects without multiple components. Is that happening?

Comment: It does working with the Deubg.Log(gameObj) but make it all also working very slow since it's printing many objects but it's working with the method HasAllComponents and before using the HideFlags I saw it's working fine since it colored all objects with ultiple components in yellow.

Comment: The problem started when I used the HideFlags for some reason it hided all the objects and then even when I removed the lines with the HideFlags all objects was hided I had to remove and add back the scene to see all the objects again (I have a backup of the scene). Maybe I should not using HideFlags but enable/disable somehow the objects in the else ?

Comment: Note that the objects are still there in your scene. They are simply hidden from the Hierarchy tab. If you want to see them again, set the flag to None. `gameObj.hideFlags = HideFlags.None`. To make object disappear from the scene, use the `SetActive` function.

Comment: @Programmer I edited and updated my question with what I did in this question where you answered me 17 hours ago I saw it now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53050768/how-can-i-filter-in-setsearchfilter-only-objects-that-contain-specific-component I can't use both BoxCollider and MeshRenderer using the SceneModeUtility.SearchForType and SceneModeUtility.SearchBar